# Validation get applied to textbox

Tags: angular, validation, angular5

When the page gets rendered required validation get applied by default. When I  inspect that element, it shows `ng-pristine` and `ng-invalid` class at the same time.

**In HTML** :

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" required pattern=".*(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[`~!@@#$^*|+\-_=;:()&?%'/,.<>\{\}\[\]\\]).*" [ngModel]="user.password" #password="ngModel">
```

**In TS** :

```
public user:logdetails;

ngOnInit() {  
   this.user=new logdetails();    
}

export class logdetails
 {
   password:string;
   confirmpassword:string;
 }
```

How to prevent this required validation at page load?

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: why required validation gets applies and how to prevent it.

Comment: Please add your CSS Class as well that gets applied.

Comment: There is a pattern in your `input` tag that is why it is applied by default, when do you want to apply that validation then ?

Comment: i want to apply that validation only after ng-touched

Comment: Well, if you only want the red border css class to be applied if the field is touched, then use `.ng-invalid.ng-touched` as your selector. Shameless plug: using ngx-valdemort would make your validation error messages consistent, and applied in a consistent way. https://ngx-valdemort.ninja-squad.com

Comment: If required validation not get applied before user touch the textbox then it works fine. if i remove required tag then it works fine but i want to give required validation also

Comment: @Amey read my comment again. The red border doesn't appear all by itself. It appears because you have defined some CSS rule somewhere that says that when a field has the css class ng-invalid, it should have a red border. But you don't want that. You want it to appear only if the field has the class ng-invalid **and ** the class ng-touched. So change the CSS selector to `.ng-invalid.ng-touched` instead of just `.ng-invalid`. It's a good thing that validation is always applied. You just want to not always display the red border, which is a different matter

Comment: @JB Nizet In all other forms same css works fine. hence i want to fix that validation.All you say will work fine for color matter. But i think it should not get apply on page load this is the bug it must get apply after ng-touched.

Comment: Of course it should get applied on page load. Either your form is valid, or it's not. If it's not, for example, you might want to disable the submit button, or to prevent the submission to happen. That wouldn't be possible if validation was only triggered when a field is touched. Again, what you need to do is to change **when** the error message/border is *displayed*.

Answer (score 0):

You have added required attribute to the input field and if its null or "" that means that the field is not valid. If you wish to add css classes for validation only after user has touched the field check for pristine and valid. Pristine changes to false after user has touched input field. To remove required validation you have to delete required attribute from your input field.

Comment: then what should be given to properties at begining. At start we assign empty model to input tags right? Cause  have used same in other forms also but it works fine.

Comment: Yes, but before warning the users that he has entered an invalid input field value check for formControl.pristine state, and show the warning only if pristine = false. And for code readabilty I suggest removing that pattern validation and using custom validators if you need something specific.

Comment: I have also tried the form update validity and set form pristine and untouched again but it also does not worked for me.

Comment: I also tried removing pattern but it did not fixed the issue.

Comment: If i give simple string variable it shows required validation.

Comment: required validation is applied because of the required attribute on the input field, to remove the required validation delete the attribute from input field. If you wish to set errors manully you can use setErrors function for adding errors manualy.